# How to convert existing directory into a python package in Pycharm4

Tags: python, pycharm

I have an option to `create a python package` in PyCharm in the project directory

and when i use `import newpackage` PyCharm Recognizes this.

I'm using PyCharm4, and when i try to "refractor" a directory to a package, i can't because the button is DISABLED. i can only see the convert to python module option

[image]

I've Tried adding the directory to **"paths"**

[image]

And Still No Success in getting PyCharm to recognize `import` statements

I'm using PyCharm4

My Question again,
How can i convert a directory into a python package so that PyCharm will not show an error during `import` statements

**Edit**
I do have an `__init__.py` file inside the child directory. still no luck

**Edit2** @joran

I've added the error screen like you requested, you can see the red underline marking the error

[image]

Comment: `How can i convert a directory into a python package so that PyCharm will not show an error during import statements?` please show the pycharm window with this error ... this has nothing to do with the option you mention I think

Comment: @JoranBeasley I've added the error screen in the second edit

Comment: 'import crawler.spiders'

Comment: @JoranBeasley Same result, you can see that `import crawler` itself gives an error

Comment: I guess you could rightclick the top crawler folder and "mark directory as" > "sources root"

Comment: I notice that your top crawler directory does not have an `__init__.py` file. Have you added it there?

Answer (score 10):

The reason you can not import from `crawler` is that `crawler` is not a python package. Its just a directory (as you already know)

It doesn't seem worth your time to troubleshoot what may be a bug in the IDE, when all you need to do is create the empty `__init__.py` yourself.

Having the `__init__.py` inside a child directory is not enough. Each directory needs its own `__init__.py`

Manually adding an empty file called `__init__.py` to that top level folder `crawler` folder will turn this into a python package.

Once done, refresh your Pycharm project.

Comment: Another Thing To Note Is That The Package Name Can Not Contain Any Spaces.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the project directory as a source root (right click on it > Mark directory as > Source Root), and then synchronize the project !